# Wagtail CMS - display children in reverse chronological order

Tags: wagtail

I have a web site running Wagtail CMS 2.6.1. Users have created an "Updates" page and a number of news/updates articles under it. The problem is on the "Updates" page the children are shown in alphabetical order, instead of reverse chronological order.

Can this be changed somehow from the admin interface? If not, what is the fastest way to do it in Python?

This is the the Python model (I believe):

```
class ArticleIndexPage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname='full')
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleIndexPage, self)\
            .get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        children = ArticlePage.objects.live()\
            .child_of(self).not_type(ArticleIndexPage).order_by('-date')

        siblings = ArticleIndexPage.objects.live()\
            .sibling_of(self).order_by('title')

        child_groups = ArticleIndexPage.objects.live()\
            .child_of(self).type(ArticleIndexPage).order_by('title')

        child_groups_for_layout = convert_list_to_matrix(child_groups)

        context['children'] = children
        context['siblings'] = siblings
        context['child_groups'] = child_groups_for_layout

        return context
```

Comment: Please post the relevant models.

Comment: thanks @DanSwain, added the model to the question

Comment: Also post the `UpdatesPage` and the template that is rendering this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually reorder pages ([Reordering pages](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/editor_manual/finding_your_way_around/the_explorer_page.html#reordering-pages) in the Editor's guide), but for them to be automatically ordered by date, you need to do this in code.

If your 'Updates page' only contains `ArticlePage` instances as children, then you can add the children sorted by date to the Updates page template context. See [Customising template context](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/editor_manual/finding_your_way_around/the_explorer_page.html#reordering-pages). It might look like

```py
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    ...

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['children'] = ArticlePage.objects.child_of(self).live().order_by('-date')
        return context
```

Then in the template, you can use it as

```html
{% for child in children %}
{{ child.title }}
{{ child.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

(This makes assumptions about your models' and variables' naming and templates. Feel free to change the details.)

Comment: Thanks @nimasmi, I already have `context['children'] = ArticlePage.objects.live().child_of(self).not_type(ArticleIndexPage).order_by('-date')`. The only difference I can see is the place of the `.live()` call, do you think that may be the issue?

Comment: I wonder about your use of both `ArticlePage` and `.not_type(ArticleIndexPage)`. Unless one subclasses the other, these should be mutually exclusive. I've updated my answer to check that we're talking about the same code.